# How to load Image from drawable in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, image, androidx, android-jetpack-compose

I have tried below code but it reflects nothing in the UI, I'm missing anything here?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            loadUi()
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun loadUi() {
        CraneWrapper {
            MaterialTheme {
                Image(
                    (ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(
                        resources,
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                        null
                    ) as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You can use the [**`painterResource`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/res/package-summary#painterresource) function:

```
 Image(painterResource(R.drawable.ic_xxxx),"content description")
```

The resources with the given id must point to either fully rasterized **images** (ex. PNG or JPG files) or **`VectorDrawable`** xml assets.
It means that this method can load either an instance of `BitmapPainter` or `VectorPainter` for `ImageBitmap` based assets or vector based assets respectively.

Example:

```kotlin
Card(
    modifier = Modifier.size(48.dp).tag("circle"),
    shape = CircleShape,
    elevation = 2.dp
) {
    Image(
        painterResource(R.drawable.ic_xxxx),
        contentDescription = "",
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: How can u get imageresource from a url via picasso? Picasso.load u can pass on a imageview to it

Comment: Or `vectorResource` if it's a vector image.

Comment: And use Coil for remote image urls.

Comment: Can you point to some doc that explains other types of images generally used in Android. I want to know which type of images are not supported with this.

Comment: In case anyone is struggling with the import `import androidx.compose.foundation.Image`

Answer (score 31):

Starting at version `1.0.0-beta01`:

```kotlin
Image(
    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.your_drawable),
    contentDescription = "Content description for visually impaired"
)
```

Answer (score 13):

Try This one but if you copy the code and then paste it I don't know why but it won't work so just type it as it is and replace the image id

```kotlin
Image(
  painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.tanjim),
  contentDescription = null,
)
```

Answer (score 7):

As `imageResource`is not available anymore, the solutions with `painterResource` are indeed correct, e.g.

```
Image(painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_heart), contentDescription = "content description")
```

But you can actually still use Bitmap instead of drawable if you need so:

```
Image(bitmap = bitmap.asImageBitmap())
```

`.asImageBitmap()` is an extensions on Bitmap that compose provides and it creates an ImageBitmap from the given Bitmap.

Answer (score 6):

Working in `0.1.0-dev14`

Loading drawable in Image could be achieve from this:

```
Image(
      imageResource(id = R.drawable.scene_01),
      modifier = Modifier.preferredHeightIn(160.dp, 260.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
      contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
   )
```

Now, I'm trying to upload drawable in Circle Image that sounds tricky but too easy in **JetPack Compose**. You can do achieve in this way:

```
Image(
         asset = imageResource(id = R.drawable.scene_01),
         modifier = Modifier.drawBackground(
                    color = Color.Black,
                    style = Stroke(4f),
                    shape = CircleShape
          ).preferredSize(120.dp)
                    .gravity(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                    .clip(CircleShape),
          contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight
      )
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: `imageResource` in not available anymore

Answer (score 4):

version=1.0.0-beta01,use `painterResource`,`imageResource` has been deleted.

example

```
Image(
    painterResource(R.drawable.ic_vector_or_png),
    contentDescription = null,
    modifier = Modifier.requiredSize(50.dp)
)
```

[android developer doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/res/package-summary#painterresource)

Answer (score 3):

With version **1.0.0-beta01**

It's like below

```kotlin
Image(
  painter = painterResource(R.drawable.header),
  contentDescription = null,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Composable
fun loadUi() {
val image = +imageResource(R.drawable.header)
    CraneWrapper {
        MaterialTheme {
            Container(expanded = true,height = 180.dp) {
                //Use the Clip() function to round the corners of the image
                Clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)) {
                //call DrawImage() to add the graphic to the app
                    DrawImage(image)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think DrawImage is available anymore :(

Answer (score 1):

I found that there is a function **imageFromResource()** in AndroidImage.kt:

```
fun imageFromResource(res: Resources, resId: Int): Image {
    return AndroidImage(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId))
}
```

so your code would be:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        loadUi()
    }
}

@Composable
fun loadUi() {
    CraneWrapper {
        MaterialTheme {
            val image = imageFromResource(resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            SimpleImage(image)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not able to get `AndroidImage` can you please share the reference?

Comment: I think it's internal, you should only use val image = imageFromResource(resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher)

Comment: It is showing compile time error, because of `imageFromResource` is nowhere to be found. Can you share the internal class name where this method is defined?

Comment: You may have an older version of compose. I have followed the steps from here: https://android.jlelse.eu/jetpack-compose-primer-92ff005b7ce2. The imageFromResource function is in androidx.ui.painting.AndroidImage.kt. Here it is: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/ui/core/src/main/java/androidx/ui/painting/AndroidImage.kt

Comment: From where is ```resources```? Can't find any here.

Comment: Not seeing this anywhere.  Please include what package this is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I found [SimpleImage](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/ui/material/src/main/java/androidx/ui/baseui/SimpleImage.kt) class from jetpack compose library to load the image but this is a temporary solution, and I didn't find any styling option with this yet.

```
// TODO(Andrey) Temporary. Should be replaced with our proper Image component when it available
@Composable
fun SimpleImage(
    image: Image
) {
    // TODO b132071873: WithDensity should be able to use the DSL syntax
    WithDensity(block = {
        Container(width = image.width.toDp(), height = image.height.toDp()) {
            Draw { canvas, _ ->
                canvas.drawImage(image, Offset.zero, Paint())
            }
        }
    })
}
```

I have used it in this way

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            loadUi()
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun loadUi() {
        CraneWrapper {
            MaterialTheme {
                val bitmap = (ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(
                        resources,
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                        null
                    ) as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
                SimpleImage(Image(bitmap))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Still, I'm not sure this is the correct way of loading image from drawables.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `Drawable` instance, you can use Accompanist Drawable Painter:

https://google.github.io/accompanist/drawablepainter/

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-drawablepainter:<version>") // TODO: Replace <version> with actual version
}
```

Example:

```kotlin
Image(
    painter = rememberDrawablePainter(drawable = yourDrawable),
    contentDescription = yourContentDescriptionIfAny,
)
```

Comment: can not work with `height(IntrinsicSize.Min)`

Answer (score -1):

Google updated their API. For `0.1.0-dev03` loading images is synchronous and is done this way

`val icon = +imageResource(R.drawable.ic_xxx)`

To draw the image

```
Container(modifier = Height(100.dp) wraps Expanded) {
   DrawImage(icon)
}
```

Currently the above code relies on you specifying either the exact height or width. It seems that scaling the image is not supported if you want for example 100 dp height and `wrap_content` instead of `Expanded` which expands the full width.
Does any one know how to solve this issue? Also is possible to fit the image inside it's container like old way `scaleType=fitCenter`?